# Instagram blocking login attempts from selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web-scraping, instagram

I'm attempting to run a bot that scrapes information from a user's bio on instagram but have recently run into a problem. Originally, I was able to do this with no problem however the more I started to scrape the more problems I noticed. First, instagram prevented my account from loading a user's profile. I waited a day before trying again (as it usually resets after 24hrs) and was able to do so for about 30 minutes before a new issue arose. I am now totally unable to login to instagram using the webdriver! I thought maybe my account got banned but I *am able* to login through chrome normally. It is only when running chrome using the webdriver that my login attempts are blocked. I have tried using proton VPN as I thought it could be an IP block but this hasn't worked either.

The error message on instagram is "There was a problem logging you into Instagram. Please try again soon."

EDIT: Using a different VPN solves this problem